# Writing in Ancient Greek with babel

Tags: babel, babel-greek

I'm using babel to write in ancient greek.

I'm interested in LGR Latin transliteration, which is described in the following table (taken from [here](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/language/babel/contrib/greek/README.html#lgr-latin-transliteration)):

[image]

Everything worked fine, except for the *perispomeni* (as in ᾶ) and the *dialytika* (as in ϊ). Here's what happened:

CODE:

```
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}

\textgreek{'a, <a, >a, `a, a|, ~a, ¨i}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

The last characters should be ᾶ and ϊ respectively.

How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not an expert but shouldn't be used polyglossia package? From the polyglossia manual:
6.17
greek
Options:
‣ variant = monotonic (= mono), polytonic (= poly), or ancient
‣ numerals = greek or arabic
‣ attic = *true or false

`http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.pdf`

Comment: No, no no...switch the green check mark to @egreg that have done a complete answer and more correct instead of mine. Please switch, it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano, I've marked yours because I had read it first and it solved my problem. But I guess you have a point, and it was a noble gesture on your part.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The perispomeni used to work. The fix is easy, though.

For the dialytika the character to use is `"`, not `¨`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek.polutoniko,english]{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xapptocmd{\greektext}{\edef~{\string~}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\textgreek{'a, <a, >a, `a, a|, ~a, "i}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, you can also directly input the precomposed letters with the diacritics (not with the combining accents).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek.polutoniko,english]{babel}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xapptocmd{\greektext}{\edef~{\string~}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\textgreek{'a, <a, >a, `a, a|, ~a, "i}

\textgreek{ά, ἁ, ἀ, ὰ, ᾳ, ᾶ, ϊ}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't contend with the " maestro " :-)

Answer (score 7):

Here, there is my answer done with `greek.polutoniko` package + the `\` to have the correct `\~a`, and `\"i`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[greek.polutoniko,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\textgreek{'a, <a, >a, `a, a|, \~a, \"i}

\end{document}
```

I add the screenshot compiled with `LuaLaTeX`.

[image]

However also your code works fine if you use the correct commands.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\textgreek{'a, <a, >a, `a, a|, \~a, \"i}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `\textgreek` macro only changes *font encoding*, not the *language*. Using `\foreignlanguage{greek}` is preferred
(unless you are compiling with XeTeX and LuaTeX and using Unicode fonts but still want the Latin transliteration).

The dialytika is input with the ASCII `"` (quotation mark) character.

The standard "monotonic" Greek orthography does not use the
perispomeni accent, therefore the tilde character `~` is kept at its default LaTeX function: insert a no-break space.
You can use a tilde *accent command* instead:

```
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}

\foreignlanguage{greek}{'a, <a, >a, `a, a|, \~a, "i}
```

If you want to write "polytonic" Greek or "ancient" Greek, use the
"polutoniko" or "ancient" modifier respectively to tell Babel. Then, the `~` character changes its meaning in Greek text parts. E.g.

```
\usepackage[greek.ancient, english]{babel}

\foreignlanguage{greek}{'a, <a, >a, `a, a|, ~a, "i}
```

Caveat: Due to side effects, the re-definition of `~` is only done
with 8-bit TeX (pdftex) and only in text parts with the *language* Greek (i.e. not in the argument of `\textgreek` inside an English text part).

**Hint**: after a first compilation, you can replace the Latin transliteration with the literal Greek characters copied from the output. Looks better, works better, is safe for use with Xe/LuaTeX.

For side-effects and details, see the [babel-greek](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel-greek) documentation.

Comment: Welcome to tex,sx.