Bibliography entries giving 'string 'x' untranslated' errors while using BibLaTeX
In my current thesis document, all my references keep generating errors claiming that there are 'untranslated' entries and there are boldened question marks in the references as well, how does one fix this? I added a simplified version of the main.tex file below, and I used the XeLaTeX compiler.
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Language support
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ipa}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Junicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}

% Set page size and margins and other useful stuff
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    top=2cm,
    bottom=2cm,
    left=2.5cm,
    right=2cm,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}

% For code
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}

% More colours
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}

% Tables
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

% Colored Text
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{codegray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{codegray}{\texttt{#1}}}

% Math
\let\eth\relax
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{mathalfa}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{width=.7\textwidth,compat=1.18}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\let\emptyset\varnothing

% Figures
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,patterns,angles,quotes,shapes.geometric,arrows,intersections}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

% Authors
\usepackage{authblk}

% References and Links
%\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=Sepia,citecolor=red
]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{#1}}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ieee,
    citestyle=numeric-comp,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Citation.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Altfeder2010, Kim2015}

\newpage
\printbibliography[
heading=bibintoc,
title={References}
]

\end{document}

And then the example references for the Citation.bib file:
@article{Altfeder2010,
   abstract = {Field-induced phonon tunneling, a previously unknown mechanism of                                 interfacial thermal transport, has been revealed by ultrahigh vacuum inelastic scanning tunneling microscopy (STM). Using thermally broadened Fermi-Dirac distribution in the STM tip as in situ atomic-scale thermometer we found that thermal vibrations of the last tip atom are effectively transmitted to sample surface despite few angstroms wide vacuum gap. We show that phonon tunneling is driven by interfacial electric field and thermally vibrating image charges, and its rate is enhanced by surface electron-phonon interaction. ©2010 The American Physical Society.},
   author = {Igor Altfeder and Andrey A. Voevodin and Ajit K. Roy},
   doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.105.166101},
   issn = {00319007},
   issue = {16},
   journal = {Physical Review Letters},
   month = {10},
   title = {Vacuum phonon tunneling},
   volume = {105},
   year = {2010},
}

@article{Kim2015,
   abstract = {Radiative transfer of energy at the nanometre length scale is of great importance to a variety of technologies including heat-assisted magnetic recording, near-field thermophotovoltaics and lithography. Although experimental advances have enabled elucidation of near-field radiative heat transfer in gaps as small as 20-30nanometres (refs 4, 5, 6), quantitative analysis in the extreme near field (less than 10nanometres) has been greatly limited by experimental challenges. Moreover, the results of pioneering measurements differed from theoretical predictions by orders of magnitude. Here we use custom-fabricated scanning probes with embedded thermocouples, in conjunction with new microdevices capable of periodic temperature modulation, to measure radiative heat transfer down to gaps as small as two nanometres. For our experiments we deposited suitably chosen metal or dielectric layers on the scanning probes and microdevices, enabling direct study of extreme near-field radiation between silica-silica, silicon nitride-silicon nitride and gold-gold surfaces to reveal marked, gap-size-dependent enhancements of radiative heat transfer. Furthermore, our state-of-the-art calculations of radiative heat transfer, performed within the theoretical framework of fluctuational electrodynamics, are in excellent agreement with our experimental results, providing unambiguous evidence that confirms the validity of this theory for modelling radiative heat transfer in gaps as small as a few nanometres. This work lays the foundations required for the rational design of novel technologies that leverage nanoscale radiative heat transfer.},
   author = {Kyeongtae Kim and Bai Song and Víctor Fernández-Hurtado and Woochul Lee and Wonho Jeong and Longji Cui and Dakotah Thompson and Johannes Feist and M. T.Homer Reid and Francisco J. García-Vidal and Juan Carlos Cuevas and Edgar Meyhofer and Pramod Reddy},
   doi = {10.1038/nature16070},
   issn = {14764687},
   issue = {7582},
   journal = {Nature},
   month = {12},
   pages = {387-391},
   publisher = {Nature Publishing Group},
   title = {Radiative heat transfer in the extreme near field},
   volume = {528},
   year = {2015},
}


This code mixes babel and polyglossia, both of which are localisation packages. This will definitely confuse biblatex and might also have other unintended consequences. In any case I don't think this combination was ever tested or officially considered supported. Choose one or the other and set up all document languages via the selected system.

I wanted to use polyglossia for a specific part since I needed to type out two words in Ancient Greek to show the etymology of something. But I don't think I can do that without this package.

babel can also deal with ancient Greek. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/584397/35864.

@moewe IMHO your first comment already could be an answer.

@Benvz If you need to use polyglossia for one language just use it for all languages. Mixing polyglossia and babel is like trying to use biblatex for some references but bibtex for others, or fancyhdr for the page headers but titleps for the page footers.

If I solely use either one of them, the text in \textgreek(πῐέζω) just becomes white space.

Have you really used \textgreek(πῐέζω) instead of \textgreek{πῐέζω}? If so, replace the ( and ) by { and }. And note, that you usually should use \foreignlanguage{greek}{πῐέζω} instead. Sorry, but without showing, what you've tried, it is hard to guess, what is wrong. BTW: You should reduce your preamble to what is needed to reproduce the issue. And note, that \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} does not make sense with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

That was a typo, I did use the angled brackets in my code. Furthermore, I am trying to work with the tips that I've been given but it's still generating some errors and not displaying the text correctly. Thanks for the other recommendation, I wasn't aware that that wasn't necessary, I still have quite limited experience with LaTeX as you might see. I'll probably leave it at this for now and re-ask the question on a later date when I am a bit more ordered and provide a minimal preamble in said question.

BTW: There are more problems with your preamble. For example you should not load lmodern. It is a legacy package to provide Latin Modern with PDFLaTeX. But you are using XeLaTeX and fontspec. Package filecontents is also deprecated … So at a first step I would really recommend to reduce the document preamble to what you really use and need. This is easy to do by commenting lines and see the changes. Or start from scretch and add only the really needed packages. Unfortunately, it is a common beginner's mistake to litter the document preamble with everything you have ever seen.

After removing the deprecated packages that you mentioned, I reattempted to fix the problem. I changed the 'Language Support' part to be more limited with just
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Junicode}
and
\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]     {\bgroup\greekfont{#1}\egroup}
After babel, ipa, and fontspec.

Never use polyglossia with babel. Never ever. They aren’t compatible and deal with languages in different ways (often quite different).
From the comments to the original post, it seems what you actually want is just to write a few words in Ancient Greek, which is one of the languages available in babel. In such a case, set the font for ancientgreek and use the language where required. That's all. Here is a minimal document:

\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelfont[ancientgreek]{rm}{Junicode}

\begin{document}

English \foreignlanguage{ancientgreek}{πῐέζω} English.

\end{document}


